# How Kera LSTM inputs corresponds with output

Tags: python-3.x, keras, lstm

I am trying to predict the stock price with help of investor sentiments and previous stock price.

head of data frame is as under:

```
time_p               close    sent_sum  output
2007-01-03 10:00:00  10.837820  0.4   10.6838
2007-01-03 11:00:00  10.849175  0.6   10.8062
2007-01-03 12:00:00  10.823942 -0.3   10.7898
2007-01-03 13:00:00  10.810063 -0.2   10.7747
2007-01-03 14:00:00  10.680111  0.1   10.7078
```

**How I preprocess Data?**

Above df contains stock data where,`time_p` is hourly datetime(not included in model)  that coresponds to  houly closing price `close`, `sent_sum` is invostor sentiment and `output` is `labels` for model. `output` is  **shifted** upword with `df.output.shitf(-8)`  in other words I want to predict **+1 hour** into future based upon **-7 hours** `close`(price) plus **-7hours** `sent_sum` (investor sentimnets).

> I am trying to fit a model like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from pandas_datareader import data
import urllib.request, json
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn import metrics
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras import optimizers
import math
import keras as k
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('AAPL_final.csv')
raw= data.iloc[:,[2,3]].values
raw2= data.iloc[:,[4]].values
#############scalling fo data######
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
scaler_y = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
scaled_x = scaler.fit_transform(raw)
scaled_y = scaler_y.fit_transform(raw2)
########tran test set##############

train= scaled_x[:14000].reshape(2000,7,2) # Train_X data
train_= scaled_y[:14000].reshape(2000,7,1) #train_Y
test_xdata= scaled_x[14000:17542].reshape(506,7,2)# Test_x
test_ydata= scaled_y[14000:17542].reshape(506,7,1)#Test_y 
train_x,train_y=  train, train_
test_x, test_y = test_xdata, test_ydata

print('shapes of tranx,teainy,testx and testy',train_x.shape, train_y.shape, test_x.shape, test_y.shape)
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100,input_shape=(7,2),return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(LSTM(100,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='sgd',metrics=['accuracy', 'mae', 'mape', 'cosine'])#sgd#rmsprop
```

> **My Questiton:** I suspect that once I have alreay shifted the label data with -7 points round the way matched current inputs with +7 hours in future time period is it ok to write `train_= scaled_y[:14000].reshape(2000,7,1) #train_Y` in `(2000,7,1) shape` or I am doing something worge.
>
> - Secondly, I am confused with how keras_lstm matches input with labels, I mean how input_shape really works?
> - Is there any good way to fit this model?, please suggest.
>     I shall be grateful for the help.

Comment: If i am right, you are trying to predict stock price for next hour on the basis of last 7 histories?

Comment: `yes.exaclty`That is what I am trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like following on the `scaled_x` and `scaled_y`

I used toy dataset to show an example, here data and labels are of shape ((150, 4), (150,)) initially, using the following script:

```
seq_length = 10
dataX = []
dataY = []
for i in range(0, 150 - seq_length, 1):
    dataX.append(data[i:i+seq_length])
    dataY.append(labels[i+seq_length-1])
import numpy as np
dataX = np.reshape(dataX, (-1, seq_length, 4))
dataY = np.reshape(dataY, (-1, 1))
# dataX.shape, dataY.shape

Output: ((140, 10, 4), (140, 1))
```

Like this example you can create the sequence with the `7` days data, with target for next day.

Keras LSTM layer expects the input to be 3 dims as (batch_size, seq_length, input_dims) as this

```
input_dims = # an integer
seq_length = #an integer
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(seq_length, input_dims), return_sequences=True))
```

Note: `batch_size` is not used on defining the layer, model will fill itself while `fit`.